# How to check ajax status in laravel

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5.1

i'm making app in laravel with register and login form. i have ajax login form. it works fine when user enters correct mail and pass, but if user enters incorrect mail or pass it redirect on login page. can anyone help me how to display error in login form without redirect?

```
public function login(){
  $data = Request::all();
  if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $data['email'], 'password' => $data['password']]))
   {
       return redirect('/');
   }
  else {
      return redirect('login');
  }
}
```

this is my controller code

Comment: please share some piece of code

Answer (score 2):

In the else part instead of

```
return redirect('login');
```

Use this

```
Session::flash('errorMessage', 'Authentication Failed');
return Redirect::back();
```

In the View (blade) add this

```
@if ($message = Session::get('errorMessage'))
  <div class="alert alert-danger alert-block">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
  <h4>Authentication Error</h4>
     <span class="errorText">{{ $message }}</span>
  </div>
@endif
```

(Without refresh) Try this:
In the else part add

```
return Response::json([
    'message' => 'Authentication Failed'
 ]);
```

In the Ajax success function, you can display this message from the return JSON.
Place the message in the span with class "errorText".

In View:

```
  <div class="alert alert-danger alert-block hidden">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
  <h4>Authentication Error</h4>
     <span class="errorText"></span>
  </div>
```

Remember to remove the class "hidden" using the jquery remove().

Note: Remember to include namespace Illuminate\Http\Request and Illuminate\Http\Response if necessary.

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: i want to do it without page refresh... this will refresh the page